# jquery fullCalendar xml from Google Calendar, how to prevent onClick opening event.url

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a working calendar running with google calendar, and I can fetch events from it to jQuery FullCalendar Plugin.

When trying to use `onClick` function to *prevent* clicking from taking me back to Google Calendar details page, nothing works. I want to open up a different page, created on-the-fly.

Documentation says:

> Normally, if the Event Object has its url property set, a click on the event will cause the browser to visit the event's url (in the same window/tab). Returning false from within your function will prevent this from happening.
>
> Often, developers want an event's url to open in a different tab or a popup window. The following example shows how to do this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            url: 'http://google.com/'
        }
        // other events here
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

When I try to do this as said, I still end up to Google Calendar details. I tried to `alert('event.url')` and it returned `undefined`. Why?

Here is my code, (everything else is running just beautifully):

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    //alert(event.url);
    if (event.url) {
        window.open(event.url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the test page: http://www.equstom.fi/equcal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by ripping away the url to google details:

```
eventClick: function(e) {  
            var target = $(this).find('a').attr('href', '#');
            alert(target);
            return false
        },
```